# How to select item in xcode that is off the view controller?

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3.1

I am developing an app in xcode 6.3.1. I am having trouble with the layout because a button got pushed off the edge of the view controller and is now hidden. [image: diagram of button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode's Interface Builder view, to the left of the drawing area there's a section called the Document Outline. All of the objects on the view are listed here. You can select an object here and delete it with the Delete key, or you can double-click on it to select it in the drawing area. Then you could use the arrow keys to move it back into the view, or use the property editor to the right to assign it a new position.

[image]

Comment: Note that the document outline can be collapsed. You can use Editor > Show Document Outline to expand it. There's also a button at the lower left of the canvas to do that.